# knockoutjs how populate select

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

i'm a beginner in knockout an i've some doubts.
my project is an mvc4 webapi, i can update a simple web gui actually,
but in complex gui with select ecc i don't know how to do.
When a gui present a select that must be populate with data for choice (es. category) in edit product gui, how populate select? i must call an api that return a collection of category and api that return a viewmodel for product? 
can I populate a product viewmodel with category collection?
in conclusion what direction i take?

thank's

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below example from knockoutjs.com

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Thanks
Naren

Comment: i've just seen this example, but